# chomping file down

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I have a big log file, over 1 million lines.
I need to use regexp to find a pattern and then start chomping down until I hit another regular expression. So I would end up with something like 1500 lines.

I know sed allows use of regexp, but can it split files? I have no experience with awk, but I think that this should allow me to do what I need. I am confused from reading the manpage though... I would appriciate some examples or even more simpler solutions.

Comment: Can you provide some sample log file lines and regexps that you hope to match?  It's always easier to work out a solution when there's some concrete input and output to talk about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both AWK ans SED you can define a RegEx like this -

**AWK:** In AWK you would notice that we haven't written `print` anywhere. In AWK (which is based on pattern/action statements, print is the default action whenever the pattern statement is true. Hence the in following case, whenever the RegEx pattern is true, AWK would print it for us.

```
awk '/regex1/,/regex2/' INPUT_FILE > NEW_FILE
```

**SED:** In SED we use a -n option to suppress default behaviour of printing everything and use the RegEx with `p` to tell SED for printing specific lines.

```
sed -n '/regex1/,/regex2/p' INPUT_FILE > NEW_FILE
```

Alternatively, you can also give the following one-liner

```
sed '/regex1/,/regex2/!d' INPUT_FILE > NEW_FILE
```

Using the redirection operator `>` you can create a subset of your file.

For *Splitting files in AWK*, if you know the Number of Records in your file (`wc -l < INPUT_FILE`) then you can write something like this -

```
awk 'NR==2,NR==5' INPUT_FILE
```

NR is AWK's built-in variable that gets set to the Record's Line Number. So if you have a file with 1500 lines and need  just top 750, then you can do something like this -

```
awk 'NR==1,NR==750' INPUT_FILE
```

As mentioned earlier, you can but you don't have to mention `print` with AWK. It does it for you as long as your pattern is true.

Though with a million lines in your file, this will be a major pain. So the following AWK one-liner should do the trick.

```
awk '{print >("SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_" int((NR+2)/3))}' BIG_INPUT_FILE
```

This one-liner will create SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_ containing 3 lines each. You can set this to your comfort level. (NR+2/3)

**Execution:**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat BIG_INPUT_FILE 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{print >("SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_" int((NR+2)/3))}' BIG_INPUT_FILE

[jaypal~/Temp]$ ls -lrt SMALL*
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  3 25 Nov 10:41 SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_4
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  6 25 Nov 10:41 SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_3
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  6 25 Nov 10:41 SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_2
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  6 25 Nov 10:41 SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_1

[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_1 
1
2
3
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_2 
4
5
6
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_3
7
8
9
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat SMALL_BATCH_OF_FILES_4
10
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer with lots of examples. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`perl -ne 'print if /start pattern/ .. /end pattern/'` will print *any* sequence of lines beginning with one that matches `/start pattern/` and ending with one that matches `/end pattern/`. If you want to bail out after the first such block you could use `perl -ne 'print if /start pattern/ .. 0; last if /end pattern/'`.

The first one can also be done in awk: `/start pattern/, /end pattern/ { print }`.

The second one can probably be done in awk too, but I don't know that much awk.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of a solution that has already been suggested

```
awk '/regexp1/,/regexp2/'
```

Supposed your input file is

```
0 zzz
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
4 aaa
5 ddd
6 ccc
7 aaa
8 ddd
9 eee
10 ddd
11 zzz
```

the command

```
awk '/a/, /d/' file.txt
```

will extract two subsets: lines 1 to 5 (note `4 aaa` is ignored) and lines 7 to 8 (note `10 ddd` is ignored)

```
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
4 aaa
5 ddd
7 aaa
8 ddd
```